# ITfoxtec - appliesToAddress value on IdPInitiatedController

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Does anyone know what the appliesToAddress variable value should be on the IdPInitiatedController of the ITfoxtec TestWebApp project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appliesToAddress` in [TestWebApp](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/IdPInitiatedController.cs#L31) is the receiving systems `issuer` also called `realm`.